# Windows Phone 8 unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-8

I want to use unit tests in my Windows Phone 8 C# application. I read [this microsoft article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/01/31/windows-phone-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-2012-update-2.aspx) about unit testing WP8 applications

I got Visual Studio 2012 Professional, updated to CTP Update 2 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36539)

But I have not got **Windows Phone Unit Test App** project type, why? I had installed all files from last CTP Update 2.

Answer (score 0):

According to the article, the FAQ section refers to the following known issue:

- After installing all the prerequisites I still do not see the Windows Phone Unit Test template.

Workaround: install the prerequisites in order on the system drive.

VS 2012

Windows Phone SDK 8.0

VS 2012 Update 2 CTP2

Comment: I have installed all of this elements, but I still can not find "Windows Phone Unit Test" project type :(

Answer (score -3):

With the [latest update](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/visual-studio-update) your issue should go away

Comment: Please elaborate little bit

Comment: You should explain why that might fix the problem.